# How to find the area of the red-colored enclosure?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, arc-length

I am helping someone prepare for an exam. And there came up this problem.

[image]

- What is given is:

  1. The angle α is 90°.
  2. The two sides of the triangle have a length `a`, i.e. it is an isosceles triangle.
- What we can infer (or at least what I tried to infer):

  1. The semi-circle divides the side of the triangle equally into two parts of length `a/2`.
  2. The perpendicular from the point of the semi-circle to the base of the triangle would be also then `a/2` long.
  3. Thus the radius of the semi-circle is `a/2` and hence the area of the semi-circle is:

> π`(a/2)²`

4. Now since the 2 sides of the triangle are of the same length `a` and the angle α is a right angle, the lenght of the base of the triangle can be found as:

> $a*\sqrt{2}$

5. The area of the right-angled triangle can be calculated as:

> 1/2 (base) x (height)

which is,

> 1/2 (a*a)

So far so good. I have the area of the semi-circle and the area of the triangle.

Now how to find out the area of the red-shaded portion? I don't have any further hints or anything in the problem statement.

Comment: How is the arc that bounds the red shape from the right determined?

Comment: Could that arc be part of a circle centered at the left vertex of the big triangle, with radius $a$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, exactly. I do not have this information. That 2nd arc has some angle, that is not mentioned in the problem. It only seems to have the same radius as the semi-circle.

Comment: All that is mentioned there is, that the final answer is, in terms of `&pi;` and `a` - the length of the side of the triangle.

Comment: I wanted to tell to the person I am helping out, that the problem in it's current form is not solvable. Or there is some misprint somewhere and the full information is missing. Just thought if somebody here at math exchange had other ideas.

Comment: I tested the arc in question using MS-Visio. It is a part of a circle with radius $\mathbf{a}$. Its center lies on the thin straight line drawn from one of the two equal sides of the triangle.

Comment: The distance between the centers of the two circle is approximately equal to $\frac{a}{4}$.